# How to use math.Net numerics in Visual Studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mathnet-numerics

I am just testing to see if I can utilize math.Net Numerics for upcoming Linear Algebra classes and I am having trouble.  I normally use R and Python but I felt like testing this out.  I literally am brand new to Visual Studio.  For some reason I get like 26 errors when trying to just test how to script for instance the first example in this website below.  I added the math.Net Numerics 3.20.0 in the NuGet Package Manager.  I also have attached what my UI looks like.  Anybody know how I need to start the script.  Do I need to open with a class and method?[image]

https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/#Using-Math-NET-Numerics-with-C

Here is the code:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

Matrix<double> A = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] {
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,2,3,4},
        {4,3,2,1}});
Vector<double>[] nullspace = A.Kernel();

// verify: the following should be approximately (0,0,0)
(A* (2* nullspace[0] - 3* nullspace[1]))
```

Here are the errors when I copy and paste code into a new project in VS.

Error   CS8124  Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Error   CS1026  ) expected
Error   CS1031  Type expected
Error   CS8124  Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Error   CS1026  ) expected
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Error   CS1031  Type expected
Error   CS0650  Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type.
Error   CS0270  Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)
Error   CS1002  ; expected
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Error   CS1031  Type expected
Error   CS0650  Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type.
Error   CS0270  Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression) 
Error   CS1002  ; expected
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Error   CS0116  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
Error   CS0116  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
Error   CS0214  Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context
Error   CS0208  Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('?')
Error   CS0102  The type '' already contains a definition 
Error   CS0214  Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe 
Error   CS0208  Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('?')
Error   CS0102  The type '' already contains a definition
Error   CS0103  The name 'A' does not exist in the current context
Error   CS0103  The name 'A' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

NVM figured it out.

```
using System;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;


namespace check1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Matrix<double> A = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] {
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,2,3,4},
        {4,3,2,1}});
            Vector<double>[] nullspace = A.Kernel();

            // verify: the following should be approximately (0,0,0)
            Console.Write(A * (2 * nullspace[0] - 3 * nullspace[1]));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```